# AWS Lambda function snapshot start_time different to snapshot started time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snapshot, boto3

I used a AWS Lambda function to create snapshots and I added to created value in the snapshot description. Now I am trying to delete snapshots based on the **Started** value but when I request this value using boto3 SDK is really different

```
| Snapshot ID            | Description                  | Started                            |
|:----------------------:|:----------------------------:|:----------------------------------:|
| snap-09829e2235d1c6ac9 | Description....at 02-03-2017 | March 1, 2017 at 11:53:04 PM UTC-5 |
```

So my question is how do I get the **Started** value for the snapshot. I need that value but boto3 is always the date with a different time and you can see in the description date time is different to date from the Started column.

### Snapshot Implementation

This is my code. Let me know if anything is wrong. Maybe I am missing something but I don't know what is it.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
REGION_NAME = os.environ['REGION_NAME']

period = 'hourly'

# Creating the client using access_key and secret key. 
client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY ,
    region_name = REGION_NAME
)

rds_client = boto3.client(
    'rds',
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY ,
    region_name = REGION_NAME
)

ses_client = boto3.client(
    'ses',
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY ,
    region_name = REGION_NAME
)

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def get_volume_tags(volume_tags):
    result_tags = {}
    for tag in volume_tags:
            if not tag['Key'].startswith('aws:'):
                result_tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
    return result_tags

def set_snapshot_tags(snapshot, tags):
    for tag_key, tag_value in tags.iteritems():
        snapshot.create_tags(
            Tags=[
                {
                'Key': tag_key,
                'Value': tag_value
                }
            ])

def get_volumes():
    return client.describe_volumes(
        Filters=[{
            'Name': 'tag:MakeSnapshot',
            'Values': [ 'True']
        }])['Volumes']


def create_volumes_snapshots():

    volumes = get_volumes()

    for volume in volumes:
        volume_id = volume['VolumeId']
        volume_tags = get_volume_tags(volume['Tags'])

        try:
            description = '%(period)s_snapshot %(vol_id)s by script at %(date)s' % {
            'period': period,
            'vol_id': volume_id,
            'date': datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            }

            volume_resource = ec2.Volume(volume_id)
            snapshot = volume_resource.create_snapshot(Description=description)
            if snapshot:
                set_snapshot_tags(snapshot, volume_tags)
                print('Snapshot created with description: %(description)s' % { 'description': description })

        except Exception, e:
            error = 'Error creating volume: %(vol_id) at %(date)s' % {
            'vol_id': volume_id,
            'date': datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            }
            print(error)
            # print(e)
            pass

def create_hourly_snapshot(event, context):

    # try:
        # creating volume snapshot process
    create_volumes_snapshots()
```

Comment: It looks like the value in the Description field is local time, while the value in the Started field is in UTC.

Comment: The Started field is actually in UTC-5 (which corresponds to America/New_York on March 1, before the recent time change).  But with no code showing, it's hard to guess how it got that way.

Answer (score 0):

The "Started" field is seven minutes to midnight **UTC**. Presumably you're in a timezone east of that and used local time in the description?

As a general piece of advice, using UTC for everything except the end user presentation layer saves you from dealing with massively complex issues in your code.